# How to read .txt into a list of Python objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a card game using Python. I have this text file below that is the Card ID, Card Name, Card Description, and Card Hit Point.

```
1, Medusa, Feel The Wraith, 98
2, Gigle , See Him See Him, 54
3, Brozi , Pinch an inch, 91
```

I have this class that is just a card. What I want to do is have a Deck (list) of these Cards (Class Objects). Here is some code that I am trying to do that will read the text file and place them into objects and then into the list.

```
import sys
import os
class Card:
    def__init__(self, card_id, name, desc, hp):
        self.card_id = card_id
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.hp = hp
        self.cards = []

deck = []

fh = open('dets.txt').readlines()
for line in fh:
    row = line.split(',')
    card_id, name, desc, hp = [i.strip() for i in row]
    card = deck.get(card_id, Card(card_id, name, desc, hp))
    deck[card_id] = card
```

Am I on the track?

Comment: Did you get any error?  Or is it working fine?

Comment: If you just want general feedback then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit

Comment: @goodknight, are you aware that list indices of a list `l` start at 0 up to `len(l) - 1`?

Comment: I try to print the object and I am not getting the right results. I think I am not printing the whole thing correct?

Comment: put space in between `def ` and `__init__` @goodknight

Comment: @goodknight, I have added an answer to your question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to put those card objects in a list, do this:

```
deck = []
fh = open('dets.txt').readlines()
for line in fh:
    row = line.split(',')
    card_id, name, desc, hp = [i.strip() for i in row]
    card = Card(card_id, name, desc, hp)
    deck = deck + [ card ]
```

Else, by looking at your code, I think you want to store them in a dictionary with `card_id` as `key`. To store them in a dictionary,

```
deck = {} #dictionary
fh = open('dets.txt').readlines()
for line in fh:
    row = line.split(',')
    card_id, name, desc, hp = [i.strip() for i in row]
    card = Card(card_id, name, desc, hp)
    deck[card_id] = card #'card_id' is the 'key' and 'card' is 'value'
```

To print the name of cards in the dictionary, use `for-loop`,

```
for each_key in deck:
    print(each_key, " - ", deck[each_key].name )
```

This will give output:

```
1  -  Medusa
2  -  Gigle
3  -  Brozi
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the bottom part:

```
deck = []

with open('dets.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        row = line.strip().split(', ')
        deck.append(Card(*row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using list and it doesn't have any method as get.
Try using a dictionary

It'll help you retrieving class object

ex.

```
myDict = {card_id1 : CardObject1, card_id2 : CardObject2, ....}
```

So when you want to get object of a card, just type this

```
if card_id in myDict.keys():
    myDict(card_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code a lot, and also make it more Python by doing the following:

1. Use `with open('dets.txt') as f` to read your file. You should close a file when you open it, and this context manager allows you to close it no matter what happense while you are reading your file.
2. Cosidering that the order of the parameters per line is the same order of the arguments you defined in your init method you can use a Python feature called [list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

So you, you can use the following code:

```
import sys
import os
class Card:
    def__init__(self, card_id, name, desc, hp):
        self.card_id = card_id
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.hp = hp
        self.cards = []

deck = []

with open('dets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        args = line.strip().split(', ')
        args[0] = int(args[0])
        args[-1] = int(args[-1])
        deck.append(Card(*args))
```

#### Considering you are using Python 3.7+

You can use `dataclases` to simplify your class definition as follows:

```
@dataclass
class Card:
    card_id: int
    name: str
    desc: str
    hp: int
```