# Turning rows in a txt file into a objects in a class that will be stored in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple inventory sorting program.

I have defined my class, and created a function that will read in the TXT file and followed along the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981804/how-to-read-txt-into-a-list-of-python-objects). My issue is that I am getting an UnboundLocalError: on the second iteration of list_of_records in the last line of code.

```
    def __init__(self, artist, album, size, cost, quantity):
        self.artist = artist
        self.album = album
        self.size = size
        self.cost = cost
```

```
list_of_records = []

def read_record_data():
    file_read = open("inventory.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
    for line in file_read:
        row = line.split(",")
        cself, artist, album, size, cost, quantity = [i.strip() for i in row]
        record_entry = Vinyl(artist, album, size, cost, quantity)
        for item in record_entry:
            list_of_records = list_of_records + [item]
```

Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote some of your code to simplify it, and make `list_of_records` a global var in the function `read_record_data` - that alone should fix the UnboundLocal error:

```
list_of_records = []

class Vinyl:
    def __init__(self, artist, album, size, cost, quantity):
        self.artist = artist
        self.album = album
        self.size = size
        self.cost = cost
        self.quantity = quantity

def read_record_data():
    global list_of_records
    
    with open("inventory.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file_read:
        lines = file_read.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split(",")
        cself, artist, album, size, cost, quantity = [i.strip() for i in parts]
        record_entry = Vinyl(artist, album, size, cost, quantity)
        list_of_records.append(record_entry)
```

I wasn't sure what you where trying to achieve with this part:

```
record_entry = Vinyl(...)
for item in record_entry:
    ....
```

Your iterating for each item in `Vinyl`, but `Vinyl` is a single class, not an iterable (list)

Comment: Thanks very much. With: record_entry = Vinyl(...)
for item in record_entry: ... I was first trying to create the object for the class then use a for loop to add the objects to a list